If $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $2$, does it equal the intersection of all order 4 conjugate subgroups?

If $G$ is a group, with a normal subgroup $X$ of order $2$,
and if all subgroups of $G$ of order $4$ are non-normal and conjugate, is their intersection equal to $X$?

I have several positive examples as following:
take $G$ of order $12$, with a non-normal subgroup $H$ of order $4$. Then, $H$ has $3$ conjugates,
and $H$ is either isomorphic to $C_4$ or $C_2 \times C_2$.

An example where $H$ is isomorphic to $C_4$ is the dicyclic group of order $12$, generated by $$x:=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad y:=\begin{bmatrix}
\omega & 0 \\
0 & \omega^2
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\omega=e^{i2\pi/3}$.
The $3$ subgroups of order $4$ are $$H_1:=\langle x \rangle,H_2:=\langle xy \rangle,H_3:=\langle x^3y \rangle.$$
They intersect at the only normal subgroup of order $2$ in $G$:
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^3H_i = \{ I,-I \}.$$
More generally, the conclusion is the same for the dicyclic group of order
$4p$ where $p$ is an odd prime number:
this group is generated by
$$x:=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad y:=\begin{bmatrix}
\omega & 0 \\
0 & \omega^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\omega=e^{i2\pi/p}$.
It has $p$ subgroups $H_1,\dots,H_p$ of order $4$, which are cyclic and conjugate.
They intersect at a normal subgroup of order $2$ in $G$:
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^pH_i = \{ I,-I \}.$$
Returning to groups of order $12$, an example where $H$ is isomorphic to
$C_2 \times C_2$ is the dihedral group $D_6$. The $3$ subgroups of order $4$ also intersect at the only normal subgroup $\{e,r^3\}$ of order $2$ in $D_6$ ($r$ is the rotation rot($\pi/3$), so $r^3$ is rot($\pi$)).More generally, for any odd number $n>1$, the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ (of order $4n$) has $n$ subgroups of order $4$. They are isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$ and conjugate. They intersect at the only normal subgroup $\{e,$rot$(\pi)\}$ of order $2$.


If these order 4 conjugate subgroups are Sylow $p$-subgroups,
then the question is true. If there's a order 2 normal subgroup X of $G$,
then it must be contained in order 4 Sylow $p$-subgroups,
and the order 2 element, call it $a$, $gag^{-1}=a$ for all $g$ $\in$ $G$,
(since $X$ is normal), since Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate of
each other, then $a$ will be contained in all order 4 Sylow $p$-subgroups,
hence $\bigcap_{i} H_i = X$,
The question provides two concrete examples of order $12$, and extensions to some of the dicyclic or dihedral groups whose order is divisible by $4$.
However, it may happen that all subgroups of order $4$ of a group are non-normal and conjugate, without being Sylow subgroups. An example is $SL(2,3)$, which is of order $24$ (and has a unique subgroup of order $2$), but whose subgroups of order $4$ are three conjugate subgroups.
I found a proof for the general case.
If $H \supset X$, then we're done. The proof is same as Sylow case.
If $H \not \supset X$, still call order 2 element from $X$ as $a$,
call a different order 2 element from $H$ as $b$,
then {$e$,$a$,$b$,$ab$} is order 4 subgroup $\cong C_2 \times C_2$.
Since we require all order 4 subgroups are conjugate, that means   all order 4 subgroups are $\cong C_2 \times C_2$. Which $gag^{-1}=a$ already contained in all these order 4 subgroups.(Which contradicts $H \not \supset X$, but anyway we're done).

Let $G$ be a group with a central element $a$ of order $2$. Assume $G$ does have subgroups of order $4$, and all of them are non-normal and conjugate. Their intersection can then only be of order $1$ or $2$, so we just need to prove that it contains $a$.

If $a$ is the only element of order $2$ in $G$, we are done (since every group of order $4$ contains an element of order $2$).
Else, let $b$ be another element of order $2$. Then, the subgroup $\langle a,b\rangle$ is of order $4$, and all its conjugates contain $a$, Q.E.D.

